# Where would I start looking for documentation on the graphical mode of the Linux console?

Tags: linux-kernel, documentation, framebuffer

I'm writing my own display server as an educational exercise. Where in the Linux kernel tree would I look for documentation on the console's graphical mode?

Basically, as I understand it, Xorg takes over the tty device and also takes over the raw hardware. How can I find documentation on duplicating that action?

Comment: From the tty side this article might be useful: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/5896. It's dated so I don't know how much has changed but it looks like it would be relevant to your task.

Comment: I don't have a full or direct answer so I'm posting as a comment. You may look at the various [Wayland](http://wayland.freedesktop.org/docs/html/) compositors that are available. Wayland is seen by many as the technology to supplant/render obsolete Xorg/XFree86. If you're just starting out you may use the study of Wayland as a general study of GUI's on Linux and if you feel like you really should break away from it for some reason, do so then.

Comment: Have you poked around here too? http://kernelnewbies.org/

Comment: Take a look to the `Nano-X` sources

Comment: start from `man xorg.conf` this is good point for reading docs.

Comment: Why don't you just use the framebuffer interface (`[src]/Documentation/fb/api.txt`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for repeating but take a look to `Nano-X` sources.

```
git clone git://microwindows.org/microwin
```

In particular take a look to the files:

```
drivers/kbd_tty.c
drivers/scr_fb.c
```

What is done in the tty driver is very similar to what Xorg does, and The `devfb` *driver* is a very simple and clean implementation.

Linux's devfb frame buffers mostly rely on `ioctl` (eg: to set/get resolution) and `mmap` (to raw write/read pixels).

`devfb` is just one (easy and a bit more portable on linux) way to access the graphic hardware.

Xorg drivers instead are composed by a kernel driver and a Xorg user space interface between the driver and Xorg itself, and what happen between kernel and user side is really implementation-dependant (there isn't a standard).

You can also take a look to `SDL` or `Directfb` but Nano-X is the cleanest/easy and a display server itself, so probably could help you on other question that you'll surely meet.